# Error while install vte-eg 'No package 'libpcre2-8' found'?

Tags: make

make is giving me the following error while trying to install vte-eg

`./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install`

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.40.0 gobject-2.0 pango >= 1.22.0 gtk+-3.0 >= 3.8.0 gobject-2.0 gio-2.0 gio-unix-2.0 zlib libpcre2-8 >= 10.21 gnutls >= 3.2.7) were not met:

No package 'libpcre2-8' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables VTE_CFLAGS
and VTE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I use `zsh` as my default shell .

#### Edit:

I'm using ubuntu 16.10

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? did you install the `libpcre2-dev` package?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16.10 and yes I have .

Comment: So what does `pkg-config --modversion libpcre2-8` say?

Comment: It returns the number " 10.22 "

Comment: Well in that case it would appear to be a problem with the packaging of the vte-eg source, since the version found clearly should satisfy the stated requirement (`libpcre2-8 >= 10.21`)

Answer (score 3):

Installing `libpcre2-dev` fixed my problem

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current form your answer is not as good as it could be. Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers). - [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/792035)

Comment: Can you clarify that it was the same problem?